# Wowza get saved vod files

Tags: php, streaming, wowza

Just a quick question

How to return all files from the content directory in wowza engine via php rest api

i successfully saved my stream into mp4 file in content directory, but i can`t find any method to list it out

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is not any method in the Wowza Rest API that exposes the files in the content folder.

One workaround would be to create an HttpProvider in Wowza that list out the files in the folder
https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-create-an-http-provider